# Calculating an integral

Tags: calculus

Can somebody help me calculate me the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^1 x(\arcsin x)^2 \, dx$$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following substitution: $u=\arcsin x.$ Then $x=\sin{u}$ and 
\begin{gather}
\int\limits_{0}^1 x(\arcsin x)^2dx=\int\limits_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}{u^2\sin{u}\,d(\sin{u})}=\int\limits_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}{u^2\sin{u}\cos{u}\,d{u}}=\\ \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}{u^2\sin{2u}\,d{u}}=\frac{1}{16}\int\limits_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}{(2u)^2\sin{2u}\,d{(2u)}}=\frac{1}{16}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}{v^2 \sin{v}\,dv}. 
\end{gather}
Integrating last integral by parts (twice), as suggest Shafat Arbaz Alam, gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)?

$$\int u \,dv = uv - \int v \,du$$

You may need more than one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 x(\arcsin x)^2 d x 
= & \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1(\arcsin x)^2 d\left(1-x^2\right) \\
= & -\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(1-x^2\right)(\arcsin x)^2\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \arcsin x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $\arcsin x=\theta $ transforms the latter integral into
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \arcsin x d x
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\theta \cos ^2 \theta d \theta =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \theta d\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right) $$
Integration by parts gives
$$
I=\left[\theta\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right) d \theta= \frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{1}{4}
$$